# Nested eventlistener how to bind on first invoke

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind an event to a class selector that is loaded asynchronously. I am using a jQuery .on event listener so it will work asynchronously.

However as I am binding another event inside the eventlistener. This means I have to trigger the event twice to make the function run.

```
button.on("touchend", tapHandler);

function tapHandler() 
  button.swipe( {
    //Generic swipe handler for all directions
    tap:function() {
        banner.toggleClass("alt")
    }
  });
});
```

Is there a way to immediately invoke the nested eventlistener on the first invocation?

This jsfiddle shows the problem clearly. When using a touch device, the button has to be pressed twice for the toggleClass to be invoked.
[jsfiddle (use touch device in dev-tools)](https://jsfiddle.net/dwigt/xpvt214o/215994/)

Comment: *"I am using a jQuery .on event listener so it will work asynchronously."* That doesn't make sense. jQuery doesn't make event listeners asynchronous.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that  Using $(document).on I can delegate the event handling to the document and any children underneath this parent document. While using a specific selectorit will not work if the button has not yet been inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Okay. That's not what the question shows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to immediately invoke the nested eventlistener on the first invocation?

If you mean "...when adding it" rather than "...on the first invocation", then yes, there are at least two ways:

1. Define a named function, use it in the handler, and call it directly:

   ```
   function tapHandler()  {
     function swipeHandler() {
       banner.toggleClass("alt")
     }
     button.swipe( {
       //Generic swipe handler for all directions
       tap: swipeHandler
     });
     swipeHandler();
   });
   ```

   That just calls `swipeHandler` once and doesn't pass it an event object; looking at what it does, that seems fine. A more thorough version might loop through `button` (since jQuery objects are sets).
2. Use [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/):

   ```
   function tapHandler()  {
     button.swipe( {
       //Generic swipe handler for all directions
       tap: function() {
           banner.toggleClass("alt")
       }
     });
     button.triggerHandler("tap");
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks you very much T.J. TiggerHandler seems just what I needed!